# UWP: How to get taskbar height programmatically?

Tags: uwp, taskbar

I want to get the taskbar height programmatically in my UWP app at the start of the program? How can I get that?

Comment: There is no API that could get the taskbar height directly. May I know why you want to get that?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Actually I want to get the max area that a uwp app can get in a device. `availableHeight = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().GetDisplayRegions()[0].WorkAreaSize.Height / displayInformation.RawPixelsPerViewPixel; `
Here in this code, `availableHeight = Device_display_height - Taskbar_height` , this also serves my purpose. but in some devices, I am getting this exception,                                       
 `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView' to type 'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.IApplicationView9`

Comment: [System.InvalidCastException unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView' to type 'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.IApplicationView9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556132/system-invalidcastexception-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-applicationview-to)

Comment: Note that your question is too narrowly focused. There are other things that can prevent you from occupying the entire screen, not just the taskbar. For example, Magnifier might be docked to one of the edges of the screen. You really want the size of a maximized window, which is what the WorkAreaSize tells you.