# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'ApplicationView' to type 'IApplicationView9

Tags: uwp, display

`var displayRegion= ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().GetDisplayRegions()`
In some devices, I am getting this exception, System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView' to type 'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.IApplicationView9'. How to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 2):

The `GetDisplayRegions` API was introduced in Windows 10, version 1903 (introduced in 10.0.18362.0) ([see Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.getdisplayregions?view=winrt-19041)). This means you have to first check if the API is present on the current device [using `APIInformation.IsMethodPresent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.ismethodpresent?view=winrt-19041).